# How to know which nodes my pods of my deployment config have been deployed in OpenShift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I am new to OpenShift and I have a deployment config there. And I know how to see the node (ip) of my current pods,

the deployment config have been deployed many times, and the pods have been redeployed to many nodes as well. how can I check the history nodes that the pods have been deployed to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in OpenShift or Kubernetes in general it should not matter on which node your application runs on. This should be completely transparent to you and you should not need to care too much about which exact node your application is running on.

> I am new to OpenShift and I have a deployment config there. And I know how to see the node (ip) of my current pods,

You can see the assigned node in the OpenShift Web Console when selecting a certain Pod (there is a field for it). You can also use the following option with `oc get pods` to show the node where the Pod is running when using `oc`:

```
oc get pods -o wide
```

> the deployment config have been deployed many times, and the pods have been redeployed to many nodes as well. how can I check the history nodes that the pods have been deployed to?

When a Pod is deleted, the definition is not kept. This means this information is not available unless you specifically query it.

Comment: Ok, I just want to understand if there is a way.